# Error with reformatting the way data has been passed into a function

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I have the following code :

```
var games = ["game_1", "game_2","game_3"]

var players= [{name:"steve"},{name:"sparrow"},{name:"captain"}]

var incomingData= [{game_1:"basketball"},{game_2:"badminton"},{game_3:"pingpong"}]


//change format as shown below:

reformat=[ {name:"steve",game:"basketball"},{name:"steve",game:"badminton"},{name:"steve",game:"pingpong"}]


 incomingData.map(incomingData=>{

       games.map((game,i)=>{
               players[i].game= incomingData.game

     })
    })

console.log(players) //​​​​​[ { name: 'steve', game: undefined },​​​​​​​​​​  { name: sparrow', game: undefined },​​​​​​​​​​  { name: 'captain', game: undefined } ]​​​​​
```

I am trying to learn about how to handle objects. I am getting undefined for the list of game inside the object. I understand this approach is wrong and would like to get some suggestions regarding how to go about changing the format to the required format.

Comment: I edited the question. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what you need:

```
 incomingData.map(data=>{
     games.map((game,i)=>{
         players[i].game=incomingData[i][games[i]]
     })
 })
```

You can play with it on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yb98080t/).

So how does it work? Inside innermost function you already *see* all necessary data. All you need is to properly assing game attribute of i-th player. So you need to take `i`-th object from `incomingData` and then read attribute that is `i`-th element of `games`. So for instance for 0 element you want `incomingData[0].game_1` that is equivalent to `incomingData[0]["game_1"]` and since `"game_1"` is dynamic you replace it with `games[i]` which leads to final `incomingData[i][games[i]]`.
Note also that you have used formal parameter name of outer `map` with the same name as variable in scop effectively hiding it.  You could access that hidden variable but simpler and cleaner is to give different name, hence renamed to `data`.

Surely it can be simplified as other users shown, my goal here was to simply fix assignment leading to `undefined`. Enough for learning fundamentals, for optimal code however see one loop receipt.

Comment: what if incomingData has more objects and we want to ignore any additional objects that doesn't match with the properties in games ? for example: 
var games = ["game_1", "game_2","game_3"] and 
var incomingData= [{game_1:"basketball"},{game_2:"badminton"},{game_3:"pingpong"},{game_4:'swimming'}]

Comment: I assumed that indices are aligned, all arrays have equal size. If `players` maps to `games` by index (i.e. player[2] has games[2]) then all you need is to lookup thru `incomingData` in another loop, looking for object that has non-empty property with game name e.g. replacing `games[i]` with `incomingData.find(o=>{return o[games[i]]})`

Answer (score 1):

```
incomingData.map((data, i) => {
    players[i].game = data[ games[i] ];
});
```

You just need one loop.

Comment: much better solution :). Thank you

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var games = ["game_1", "game_2","game_3"]

var players= [{name:"steve"},{name:"sparrow"},{name:"captain"}]

var incomingData= [{game_1:"basketball"},{game_2:"badminton"},{game_3:"pingpong"}]


//change format as shown below:

var reformat=[ {name:"steve",game:"basketball"},{name:"steve",game:"badminton"},{name:"steve",game:"pingpong"}]


 games.map((game,i)=>{
               players[i].game= incomingData[i][game];
    })

console.log(players) 
}
```